# What exactly is the group Omega(n,q) in MAGMA?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, magma-cas, groups-of-lie-type

Let $n>2$ and $q$ be a prime power. In MAGMA I'm having a lot of trouble identifying the group Omega(n,q). I'm trying to use a source that asserts that it is the group of $n\times n$ orthogonal matrices that have spinor norm a square in $GF(q)$, but that isn't right because when (say) $n=5$ and $q=5$ I find plenty of matrices which aren't orthogonal, such as this one:
\ \begin{bmatrix}
3&3&4&3&4\\
0&2&0&0&3\\
2&1&2&2&3\\
3&0&0&1&0\\
2&3&3&2&4\\
\end{bmatrix}
which we can clearly see is not orthogonal (not all columns are of length 1 and the scalar product of some columns are not 0, modulo 5).
Even so, MAGMA thinks of this group as a subgroup of the GeneralOrthogonalGroup(n,q), which must have an entirely different meaning to what I thought it did. 
I'm trying to use the result that the projective symplectic group $PSp(4,q)$ is isomorphic to the group in question but I seem to be struggling to get a handle on what this group actually is.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is that the symmetric bilinear form that is preserved by this group is not what you are expecting.

```
   > G := Omega(5,5);
   > SymmetricBilinearForm(G);
     true 
     [0 0 0 0 1]
     [0 0 0 1 0]
     [0 0 3 0 0]
     [0 1 0 0 0]
     [1 0 0 0 0]
     orthogonalcircle
   > 
   > flag, form :=  SymmetricBilinearForm(G);
   > g := Random(G);
   > g * form * Transpose(g) eq form;
     true
   > newform := IdentityMatrix(BaseRing(G),Degree(G));
   > g := TransformForm(newform, "orthogonalcircle");
   > GG := G^(g^-1);
   > SymmetricBilinearForm(GG);
     true 
     [1 0 0 0 0]
     [0 1 0 0 0]
     [0 0 1 0 0]
     [0 0 0 1 0]
     [0 0 0 0 1]
     orthogonalcircle
```

Comment: Ah yes I see, of course. Is there a way to ask Magma to define the group using a different symmetric bilinear form?

Comment: Yes, by using TransformForm and conjugating. I have done this in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. The only issue with that I guess is that for larger $q$, it will take much longer for Magma to calculate the conjugate of $G$.

Comment: All it has to do is to conjugate the two generators of $G$, which will not take very long! TransformForm is the slowest part of this process for larger dimensions and field sizes.

Comment: I know this is an old post now but I'm just coming back to this and evidently I still don't understand what's going on here. I followed your instructions and was happy with it until I found that this matrix:
\\ \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&4\\
\end{bmatrix}
isn't in G. I thought for sure that with the Symmetric Bilinear Form being the identity, the group would contain all orthogonal matrices!

Comment: It doesn't have determinant $1$. If you want the group of all matrices that preserve the form, use the function $\mathsf{GO}$ in place of $\mathsf {Omega}$.