# What is an Omega group on a finite field?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

[This website](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/linear.html) refers to a class of groups as *Omega groups*. An example of such a group is [$\Omega_4^+(\mathbb{F}_3)$](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/linear.html#omega+). I have not found any other source that uses this terminology, nor am I able to discern how these groups could be defined. They appear to be further subclassed into Omega groups of $+$ type and of $-$ type, and there is a notion of a projective Omega group.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and a field $F$, how does one define $\Omega_n^+(F)$  and $\Omega_n^-(F)$?

I would assume that these are subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$. If this is the case, what matrices comprise the Omega groups? What matrices generate the Omega groups?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564517/what-exactly-is-the-group-omegan-q-in-magma) seems related.

Comment: This is standard notation for the quasisimple orthogonal groups over finite fields. The special orthogonal groups ${\rm SO}^\pm(n,q)$ ($n$ even - there are two inequivalent types of form when $n$ is even) and ${\rm SO}(n,q)$ ($n$ odd) generally have a quasisimple subgroup of index $2$ - this is the $\Omega$-group.